# Java - Nesting GridBagLayout Layout Managers

Tags: java, swing, applet, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am running into a problem with GridBagLayouts.

I have a few components laid out as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I want the "center" component to be able to move above the bottom edge of "top-right" if the "top" component shrinks small enough. However, this obviously causes a problem since it would have to be in a different row in the grid to be able to do so.

To solve this - I define the entire right column as its own container, with its own layout manager. I'd expect the two columns to be able to behave independently, however I get the same problem! I don't see how the two layout managers could possibly be interacting still. Can anyone possibly explain what my problem is?

Here is the relevant code (in my class extending Applet):

```
public void init(){
    addComponents();
}

private void addComponents(){
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    Left left = new Left();
    Top top = new Top();
    Center center = new Center();
    TopRight topRight = new TopRight();
    BottomRight bottomRight = new BottomRight();
    Bottom bottom = new Bottom();

    topRight.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    top.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,200));
    center.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,100));
    container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    c.gridx = 0; c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1; c.gridheight = 3;
    c.weightx = 0.2; c.weighty = 1.0;
    this.add(left,c);

    c.gridx = 1; c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1; c.gridheight = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.8; c.weighty = 0.8;
    this.add(top,c);

    c.gridx = 1; c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1; c.gridheight = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.8; c.weighty = 0.0;
    this.add(center,c);

    c.gridx = 1; c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 1; c.gridheight = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.8; c.weighty = 0.2;
    this.add(bottom,c);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    c.gridx = 2; c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1; c.gridheight = 3;
    c.weightx = 0.0; c.weighty = 1.0;
    this.add(container,c);

    GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    c2.gridx = 0; c2.gridy = 0;
    c2.gridwidth = 1; c2.gridheight = 1;
    c2.weightx = 0.0; c2.weighty = 0.0;
    container.add(topRight,c2);

    c2.gridx = 0; c2.gridy = 1;
    c2.gridwidth = 1; c2.gridheight = 1;
    c2.weightx = 0.0; c2.weighty = 1.0;
    container.add(bottomRight,c2);
}
```

Note: Each of the components shown (left, top, etc) is an extension of JPanel - each with its paint(Graphics g) method overridden to fill it with some color.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long read,

Jonathan

Comment: To clarify what happens when the boundaries cross - the top right component will switch sizes suddenly (well below its preferred size) so that the center component can continue to move upwards. It remains the new size until the center component is moved back past the preferred height of top-right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It had something to do with me setting the preferred height of the Top component unnecessarily - when I removed that line it worked like I was wanting.